# Как реализовать порядковый номер записей в postgress?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

Имеется сервер на nest js, база данных postgress и ORM sequelize, но данный вопрос будет справедлив идля других сочетаний БД и ORM. Необходимо присваивать порядковый номер записям для последующей сортировки на стороне клиента, причем на стороне клиента этот порядкровый номер можно менять посредством перетаскиваня карточек (Drag and Drop). Порассуждав над механикой я присвоил каждой записи свойство order, которое автоматически инкрементируется при создании записи

```
  @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        unique: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    })
    order: number
```

И даже написал метод меняющий порядковый номер двух записей, берем одну карточку перетаскиваем, на сервер улетаю id карточки которую тянули и id карточки куда бросили, соответсветнно меняем order этих карточек. И тут возникает проблема, например если мы перетаскиваем последнюю карточку в самое начало, они меняются местми, а хочется что бы последняя карточка отодвинула первую по порядку. Получается что при изменении порядка нужно менять значение order всем записям. Есть ли способ делать это автоматически по типу индесов элементов массива?

Comment: В каком виде(структура) данные приходят клиенту и как они отрисовываются? Это ведь наверняка у вас массив.

Comment: Да все верно это массив объектов выглядит примерно вот так 
{
   id: "some string"
   order: 1
   ....
}
Пока я ни чего умнее не придумал как после перетаскивания присваивать каждому объекту новый порядковый номер, формировать из масссива новых объектов объект по типу 
{
 [item.id]: item.order
}
Отправлять эти данные на сервер.На сервере получать все записи, пробегаться по ним циклом и присваивать новые порядковые номера, сохраняя при этом каждую запись в цикле. Выгляди крипово но работает

Comment: А если одну и ту же запись выберут 2 клиента? Если одна и та же запись будет в 2-х разных выборках? Как тогда должен определяться order? Просто сама задача выглядит как то не понятно

Comment: *если мы перетаскиваем последнюю карточку в самое начало, они меняются местми, а хочется что бы последняя карточка отодвинула первую по порядку* Ну так и надо выполнять запрос, который именно подвинет записи, а не обменяет местами. И ORM тут вообще не при чём.. Хотя перенумерация ВСЕХ записей при перемещении всего одной карточки - не лучшая идея..

Comment: Про двух клиентов, данные с сервера обновляются каждые 15 секунд, в дальнейшем это будет заменено на web socket. Задача достаточно проста. Есть магазин и есть crm для этого магазина. В crm можнос создавать заказы они отображаются списком, в этом списке карточки товаров можно перетаскивать что бы менять их порядок, в каком порядке товары отображаются в crm в таком же порядке они будут отображаться и у клиента

Comment: Ну так и надо выполнять запрос, который именно подвинет записи, а не обменяет местами. И ORM тут вообще не при чём.. Хотя перенумерация ВСЕХ записей при перемещении всего одной карточки - не лучшая идея. 
Если у нас есть массив [1, 2, 4, 5] при перемещени 5 элемента на место первого индексы 2, 3 и 4 обновятся, мне нужно именно такое поведение иначе перетаскивание выглядит странно и не интуитивно